# storing session information in sql server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to store session information in SQL server 2012. I have got the "ASPState" database in my management studio.now for asp.net I am using the windows authentication for SQL server .When I am trying to modify webconfig file with data source=127.0.0.1 it is not being able to connect.please help.
my webconfig file looks like this:

```
 <sessionState
  mode="SQLServer"
  sqlConnectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1"
  cookieless="false"
  />
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply.For initial catalog i think we need to set Allowcustomdatabase to true.Correct me if i am wrong.I am running sqlserver locally.

Comment: I have modified the webconfig but still not working.

Comment: mode="SQLServer"
      sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLExpress;allowCustomSqlDatabase=True; initial catalog=ASPState;integrated security=True;"
      cookieless="false"
      />

Comment: Just normal Windows explorer, check your folder permissions.

Comment: Hi sorry to bug you but could you please guide me through the process...i know its disturbing but i have never done it so requesting you.

Comment: I did not execute InstallSqlState.sql before Aspnet_regsql.exe..how can i resolve the issue?help please

Comment: i have been able to remove the state database..could someone please tell me how to configure sql server to store session data?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is very incomplete.  You'll need a lot more info.  I'll also assume that you are running SQLExpress locally.  An example string may be:

```
sqlConnectionString="data source=.\SQLExpress;initial catalog=YourDBName;integrated security=True"
```

There is a lot of info available on setting up your connection string properly.

Comment: i tried using different connectionstrings,but it is not working..i am getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error message.I checked IIS express i could not find inermgr.Is this error because of that??When i remove the session data part from webconfig things work fine..So is this a problem with IIS or the connection string?

Comment: I suspect that you also have file permissions issues in your folder structure.  Make sure that the Application Pool user has permissions to get to everything.

Comment: How to check and change that..could you please help?

Comment: Hi I have able to resolve the issue i removed the tables and reinserted them and things work fine.

Comment: yup but now when i am storing data in the session data table i cannot see any data..Could you please help me?